# Why doesn't VS2013 zero-initialize this struct?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

Using Microsoft Visual Studio Ultimate 2013 update 4 and the following code:

```
#include <iostream>

auto main() -> int {
    struct Base { int a; };
    struct Derived : Base { int b; };

    auto foo = Derived();

    std::cout << foo.a << " " << foo.b;
}
```

I get this output:

```
-858993460 -858993460
```

But I expected:

```
0 0
```

Why is `foo` not zero-initialized?

Comment: Have you tried first searching for an answer?

Comment: Because it is not supposed to.

Comment: But members should be zero-initialized, according to standard. And gcc/clang zero-initialize object, as needed.

Comment: @Dialecticus: I'm afraid this *is* his try.

Comment: @ForEveR Do you have a pointer to the relevant clause in the standard?

Comment: @PeterSchneider look at my answer, probably I can treat quotes wrong, but it seems to me, that I'm right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be initialized to zero, looks like [MSVC bug](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/802160).
Since actually your code is like this

```
Derived foo{Derived()};
```

then copy/move constructor will be called on temporary object initialized with `()`.

n3376 8.5/10

> An object whose initializer is an empty set of parentheses, i.e., (),
> shall be value-initialized.

n3376 8.5/7

> To value-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type **without a
> user-provided or deleted default construc- tor, then the object is
> zero-initialized** and, if T has a non-trivial default constructor,
> default-initialized;

n3376 8.5/5

> To zero-initialize an object or reference of type T means:
>
> if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type, **each
> non-static data member and each base-class subobject is
> zero-initialized and padding is initialized to zero bits;**

Comment: Actually it's the same as `Derived foo( (Derived()) );`.  Without the extra parentheses, you hit the most embarrassing  parse problem (and declare a function).

Comment: Wow, I would have lost 100 Dollars here easily. Did the "empty-parentheses-mean-value-initialization" rule always exist or has it been introduced with auto and braces? And I tried with VS 2013 vs gcc 4.9.2; VS does not initialize the struct, gcc does.

Comment: I'd also be interested in whether indeed a "copy/move constructor will be called on temporary object". I'd have thought that there will always be just one object which is directly initialized, along the lines of `int i=0;`

Comment: @PeterSchneider this rule was before C++11. It's not direct-initialization, it's copy initialization, but compiler can (and will) optimize it.

Answer (score 0):

Your structs have no constructors, so default one are created.

Default constructor of a struct will call default constructor for each of memebers.

Default constructor of `int` doesn't initialize it. So `int` memeber will contain random data.

Add constructors to your structs and initialize memebers. Like this:

```
struct Base
{
    Base(): a(0) {}
    int a;
};
```

Comment: OP asks _why_ it happens, not how to solve it.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I thought this post explains the "why" nicely. The question is whether it is correct (I thought it is until I read ForEverR's post). So is it??

Comment: I think it's not. if I remember correctly, If you don't ask for default constructor explicitly when you initialize a variable of struct type (if this struct have fields only with primitive types (or another similar structs) and don't have user-provided constructor that initializes these fields), then fields are not 0-initialized. See this: http://ideone.com/SkHTxi It prints garbage. Replace `Derived;` with `Derived();` at end of 9th line and it will print `0`s.

Comment: Which means that Michał is wrong, as is VC (the workaround would work though).